# How do i use Gradient with Flutter ThemeData backgroundColor property?

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to set Gradient Colors instead of a single color in flutter ThemeData's backgroundColor property?

```
final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
return base.copyWith(
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  textTheme: _texttheme(base.textTheme),
  buttonTheme: _buttonTheme(base.buttonTheme),
  inputDecorationTheme: _inputDecorationTheme(base.inputDecorationTheme),
  bottomAppBarTheme: _bottomAppBarTheme(base.bottomAppBarTheme),

  backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey // gradient color instead of single color
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't directly use a gradient in `backgroundColor` since it accepts a `Color` and not a `Gradient`, but that doesn't mean you can't make your own custom background.

If you need to update the color throughout the entire application, you may try making your own custom `Scaffold`. Otherwise, the following `GradientBackground` will let you easily create a widget with a gradient background, but you may need to customize it depending on your layout needs (such as adding alignment properties to the `Stack`.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GradientBackground(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.lightBlue, Colors.purpleAccent],
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text("Hello World!",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
          )),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class GradientBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  GradientBackground({Key key, this.gradient, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  final Gradient gradient;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: gradient,
          ),
        ),
        child,
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

[image: GradientBackground results]

Comment: Nice solution!!